# Creating new column in Spark using lit()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, typeerror, apache-spark-sql

I'm quite new to Spark and Python so perhaps this is really obvious to someone more experienced.

I've created one column manually, and want to create another column where all values are 's'. The course I'm taking suggests using the lit() function. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how. This code gives a this error: "TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable"

```
wordsDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('cat',), ('elephant',), ('rat',), ('rat',), ('cat', )], ['word'])
wordsDF.show()
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, concat
pluralDF = ([(wordsDF.word.lit(),'s',)], ['words', 's'])
pluralDF.show()
```

(I use the the show function to display the result to make sure I've got it right. If I only run line 1 and 2, it shows my list of animals, but line 4 and 5 fail.)

The code given by the tutor as a hint is this (for line 4):

```
pluralDF = wordsDF.<FILL IN>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do  it with the `DataFrame`'s method `select` and [concat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=conca#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) function.

```py
pluralDF = wordsDF.select("*", concat(df['word'], lit('s')).alias("plural"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

pluralDF = wordsDF.withColumn("words", lit('s'))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

wordsDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('cat',), ('elephant',), ('rat',), ('rat',), ('cat', )], ['word']) \
            .withColumns('words', F.lit('s'))
```

If you want to add the 's' to the end of the strings try :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

wordsDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('cat',), ('elephant',), ('rat',), ('rat',), ('cat', )], ['word']) \
            .withColumns('words', F.lit('s')) \
            .withColumns('words', F.concat(F.col('_1'), F.col('words')))
```